# Webpack alias is being ignored when module present

Tags: javascript, react-native, webpack, react-native-web

I'm aliasing the `react-native` module as `react-native-web` like this:

```
webpackConfig.resolve.alias["react-native$"] = "react-native-web";
```

If I don't have the `react-native` module installed in my `node_modules` everything works just fine, but if I install it (because I need it for my native app) the alias doesn't seem to work and it just tries to import `react-native` instead of `react-native-web`.
Is this a normal behaviour for Webpack? To ignore the alias if the module exists.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by including `react-native` to be transpiled by the babel loader. Not sure why I have to do this but as long as it works, I'm more then happy.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? How did you include it to be transpiled by the babel loader?